# Drawing a bitmap in a canvas after calling setBitmap doesn't work

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm drawing a bitmap in a canvas and I want to have the result in a new bitmap, but I still have a black screen as result.
This is my code, part of the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method:

```
if (bitmapTemplate == null) { 
    canvasBis = new Canvas();
            bitmapTemplate = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth()+30,canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            drawZones(canvasBis,bitmapTemplate);
}

bitmapRes = Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getWidth()+30,canvas.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas.setBitmap(bitmapRes);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapTemplate, matrix, null);
```

My goal is to have a new bitmap (`bitmapRes`) by applying a matrix on an existing bitmap (`bitmapTemplate`). With this code I always have a black screen, but when I remove the line `canvas.setBitmap(bitmapRes)`, I have a result but not in a new bitmap. Any ideas please? Maybe transparency? Thanks in advance.

`drawZones` draws some zones in `bitmapTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using the Canvas(Bitmap) constructor instead of the empty constructor. This sets the bitmap to the canvas for you.